# egrep not working in crontab

Tags: cron, grep

I have a simple bash script wich works fine when running in command line, but not in crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin

for f in /data/home/cwolff/tmp/*access_log*.txt;
do
egrep "r:[A-Z]+ \S+[^\.\s]{5} " $f >> $f.min
done
```

When running in crontab it outputs empty *.min files. I read about some character like % need to be escaped in crontab, but I'm not using any of them.

Comment: my crontrab entry looks like this: '22 9 * * * /data/home/cwolff/scripts/archive_access_logs.sh'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with ranges like `[A-Z]`, as the meaning of that depends on the locale. It might be `[ABC...]`, but it might also be `[AaBbCc...]`. `[:upper:]` is well-defined.

So, my best bet would be to check the environment in your login shell vs cron, especially `LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LANG`.

Comment: thanks a lot - setting the LANG env in crontab solved this issue!

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by permissions.

You would see exactly this behaviour if you have permission to read all the files in `/data/home/cwolff/tmp/*access_log*.txt` but the user whose crontab you are running this from doesn't.

This will also be the case if `/data` is mounted using NFS without the `no_root_squash` option and the crontab is root's.

Errors from cron jobs are usually mailed to the user in question.  If you haven't spent any time configuring your mail setup, these are probably in `/var/spool/mail/user`.